Placing a long text with line breaks and tabs in appsettings.json
I'm wondering if it's possible to place a very long text, with line breaks and tabs, as a string value in appsettings.json.
I'm referring to something like this:
    "SomeKey": {
       "AnotherKey": "This is a very long string value that I would like to
                      place in my appsettings.json file, with line breaks and tabs
                      so it will be readble.
                      Is there a way to achieve this?"
    },

Of course I can place the string without the line breaks and tabs, but then it won't be readable and will cause a huge scrolling in any IDE.

It's JSON, so no. You can have comments, though.

You can escape tabs and spaces \t\r\n, but they will be included in the content. And I believe you can include any raw characters except " and \.

appsettings.json is just plain json, so IMHO this is not a C#/ .net question. I modified the tags.

You can split the string into an array of lines:
{
  "SomeKey": {
    "AnotherKey": [
      "This is a very long string value that I would like to",
      "place in my appsettings.json file, with line breaks and tabs",
      "so it will be readable.",
      "Is there a way to achieve this?"
    ]
  }
}

In your C# code, you can join the array back into a single string if needed.

That doesn't answer my question. I'm trying to break the lines so they will be readble.
